# How can i enable HTTPS over a Snap server?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

is there a simple example on enabling HTTPS in a Snap server?
I am not that into OpenSsl and its usage with Snap.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://snapframework.com/faq#how-do-i-enable-ssl? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I read it, yes. I thought it will be something more programmatic , right from the server, written in the app using one of these [functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.5.1/docs/Snap-Http-Server-Config.html)

Comment: @JPMoresmau The official documentation on that is misleading, because it assumes you are using the internal cli argument  parser via `commandLineAppConfig`, which might or might not be true, depending on your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JP Moresmau showed you how to enable it from the command line, but doing the same programatically is just as easy. The function that starts Snap's "main loop" takes a configuration parameter as the first argument as you can see [in this bit of documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.5.1/docs/Snap-Http-Server.html#httpServe). You can simply call `defaultConfig` from the [Snap.Http.Server.Config](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.5.1/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Http-Server-Config.html#defaultConfig) module and then call `setSSLPort`, `setCert` and `setSSLKey` on it. Then you can pass this new config to `httpServe` as the first argument. If you used `snap init` you can find all the relevant code in your `src/Main.hs`.

As you can see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.5.1/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Http-Server-Config.html#extendedCommandLineConfig), the default config is created from the command line using [a description of options](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.5.1/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Http-Server-Config.html#optDescrs). So changing the `defaultConfig` is exactly the same as passing commandline arguments.

What I find slightly odd is that there's no `defaultSSLConfig` that generates a self-signed certificate so you can try SSL quickly. Also, it's odd the certificate and keys are of type `FilePath`. Maybe it's a good pull request for the Snap team to check?